# DOM elements manipulation by Canvas (mouse-events), what's the best practice?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, createjs, dom-manipulation

I'm creating an interactive map with Canvas (and CreateJS). I would like to have the markers in the DOM for several reasons:

- CSS hover styles
- The customer should be able to add markers in the CMS, therefore it will show up in the HTML template.
- I want to link content to each marker by using a data-attribute, the content shows up after clicking the marker. Linking elements to content/data can be easily achieved in JavaScript, so I would be able to let go of this point. But keeping it in the DOM is what I prefer for SEO purposes.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="zoom zoom-in" onclick="zoomIn()"></div>
    <div class="zoom zoom-out" onclick="zoomOut()"></div>
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <canvas id="tree" width="1500" height="1000"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here you can see the structure of my HTML. Users can pan the background of the map which is a Canvas element. Also zooming is an option. I want the coordinates of the markers to adapt to these interactions. The coordinates are set by a CSS transform.

Please give me tips about how to approach in order to keep at least a decent performance. 
Every tip is welcome!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you looked into DOMElement? You can just manage your elements as EaselJS stage objects, and let EaselJS do the CSS transforms for you. https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DOMElement.html -- DOMElement uses CSS transforms, which are fairly performant.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds like something I'm looking for. But what is the best way to map the created DOM elements to the Canvas setting? I would like the generated CSS transform to adapt to panning and zooming.

Comment: I just did it with setting the x and y value of the element manually (by a calculation). And it seems like the markers are moving fluently with the background (the pressmove event).